# Attach Existing UserForm Button to Excel Workbook Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have an Excel workbook that has a macro (the only macro in the workbook) attached to a button on a sheet.

In VB mode, I created a UserForm under Forms with a CommandButton1_Click Sub and when run from within VB (Run > Run Sub/UserForm or F5) it runs fine.  I have it calling a Shell command that runs a BAT file that runs a Python script.

How do I run CommandButton1_Click from a button on a sheet? If I try to add a button to a sheet, it offers me the macro I have already associated with the other button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one macro for example

```
Sub ShowForm
    YourForm.show
End Sub
```

And associate this macro in button.

Comment: I knew this would be easy for someone who knows VB.  I certainly don't.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This would always bring up your UserForm from the sheet button - do you actually want to do that rather than run the code directly from the worksheet button?

Comment: This proposed answer is good enough for me, although ultimately, it would be nice to simply click the worksheet button and have the same Shell command run...  So yes, I guess I would rather run the code directly from the worksheet button.  I already accepted the answer but I could always use extra help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move the main code into a new macro to modularise it. You can then call your macro via both UserForm and worksheet ActiveX (or Forms) buttons

```
'Normal Code Module
Sub TestCode()
MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub

'UserForm code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call TestCode
End Sub

'ActiveX button code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call TestCode
End Sub
```